# How to do socket pooling in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets

How to do this: What I am writing in my wall it should be visible in other's wall at same point of time which is in my chat. It seems I have to work with socket programming. How to give every character updates to the other user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SocketRocket is the most popular and a very useful Objective C library for socket programming. It has an inbuilt example for chat also. Check out: https://github.com/square/SocketRocket
You must have a web server though for testing.

Comment: Thank's for the quick response  @iphondroid